# AS3 pause button doesn't play paused song from array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, button, soundchannel

I have a flash mp3 player with a play, pause and next button on one frame.
 
The songs are stored in an array.
Everything works fine except for the
pause button. It pauses the music
 and save the song position in a variable.
When i click on the pause
 button again the song is supposed to play
from the saved song position
 which it does. The problem is it also
play the first song in the array. Not
 the song that was paused. I have tried 
to find a solution on Google. But
 the topics i could find where about mp3 players that only played one song.
 
Here is the code. Thanks.

```
var i:Number = 0;
var myMusic:Sound = new Sound();
var mySongs:Array = ["Kalimba.mp3","Sleep Away.mp3","Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3"];
var soundFile:URLRequest = new URLRequest(mySongs[i++]);
var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var sTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
var songPosition:Number;
var myContext:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(5000);
myMusic.load(soundFile, myContext);

btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMusic);
btnNext.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextMusic);
btnPause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseMusic);
channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, nextMusic);

function playMusic(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
   channel = myMusic.play(songPosition);
   channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, nextMusic);
}

function nextMusic(evt:Event):void
{
    channel.stop();
    var myMusic:Sound = new Sound();
    var mySongs:Array = ["Kalimba.mp3","Sleep Away.mp3","Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3"];
    var soundFile:URLRequest = new URLRequest(mySongs[i]);
    myMusic.load(soundFile, myContext);
    channel = myMusic.play(i);
    channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, nextMusic);
    if(i==mySongs.length-1) {
    i=0;
    }
    else {
        i++;
    }
}

var Paused:Boolean = false;

function pauseMusic(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(Paused==false) {
    songPosition = channel.position;
    channel.stop();
    Paused = true;
    }
    else if(Paused==true) {
        channel = myMusic.play(songPosition);
        Paused = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't keep adding the channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, nextMusic);

Beacuse SOUND_COMPLETE events get fired when you pause.

Adding this eventlistener just once should suffice anyway.

Comment: I removed channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, nextMusic);

Comment: To be sure i removed all the channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, nextMusic); But still no.

Comment: give songPosition a default value as well, as it isn't defined when you first press play.

Comment: Also not exactly sure why you;re using i everywhere, normally you only do that inside loops.. but u at least should remove channel = myMusic.play(i);.. to channel = myMusic.play();

Comment: songPosition now have a default value and myMusic.play(i) is now myMusic.play().

Comment: I use i as a counter for the array. So when click the next button the i increment and plays the song.

Comment: I actually think the var i:Number = 0; is the problem

Comment: I tried to change var i:Number = 0; to var i:Number = 1; When i click on play it plays the second song in the array.

Comment: When i click on the pause to start the sound again it plays from the position. But it also plays the second song in the array as defined in var i:Number = 1.

Comment: If i remove var i:Number = 0; the next button doesn't work anymore. There has to be a better way.